# Ubuntu server different kind of services

Tags: 14.04, server, virtualbox, services

I'm starting to learn more about servers and I was thinking if (and how) I can run multiple services on my Ubuntu Server. For example: I'm starting to develop a system with Django (Python) and I also want to host a wordpress blog (PHP). There is a way to do this in the same server? How can I do that? I'm using Ubuntu Server 14.04 in a Virtual Machine (Virtualbox)

Comment: You can run more than one thing on one OS, you just have to configure Apache correctly, and then do all the network routing from external -> your computer -> VBox NAT configured with port forwarding.

Comment: You start those services, but assign each one another (best the protocol's/application's default) port

Comment: Could you please indicate to me some articles and tutorials that cover this?